# Angular: Google Material Icons not rendering

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, google-material-icons

In Angular project Google material icons are working fine in chrome but not rendering in **chrome incognito mode** and **firefox** .
In **index.html** below lines are used for getting fonts library.

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

In template:

```
<mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
```

Instead of icon it show person as text.
In browser's  network tab it shows **307 Temporary Redirect** as status code for two request.

Below is output in browser:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

you'd have to use:

```
<i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
<i class="material-icons">person</i>
```

Comment: I tried it is working fine in chrome. But in chrome incognito mode and firefox same issue (307 Temporary Redirect) is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Use as :

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="person" aria-hidden="false"></mat-icon>
<mat-icon svgIcon="password" aria-hidden="false"></mat-icon>
```

Reference : https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview